# Stored procedure transactions not committing

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that has 3 transactions, each in its own `TRY-CATCH` block like this:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
        --SAVE TRAN MySavePoint1
        INSERT INTO blah blah blah;
        SET @Result1 = @@ROWCOUNT
        INSERT INTO blah blah blah;
        SET @Result2 = @@ROWCOUNT
        UPDATE blah blah blah;
    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN --MySavePoint1
    SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    SET @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
    SET @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE()
    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)
END CATCH
```

...and ending with a SELECT to return results:

```
SELECT
    @Result1 AS Result1,
    @Result2 AS Result2,
    @Result3 AS Result3,
    @Result4 AS Result4,
    @Result5 AS Result5,
    @Result6 AS Result6
```

The stored procedure is called from my app via code like this:

```
With New DBModel(SqlConnect)
    With CType(.Database.Connection, SqlClient.SqlConnection)
        AddHandler .InfoMessage, AddressOf InfoMessage
        .FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = True
    End With

    Dim Results As Results = .Database.SqlQuery(Of Results)("MyStoredProcedure").FirstOrDefault

    ' Code to handle Results here

    .Dispose()
End With
```

**Here's the issue:**

The first transaction will fail but the other 2 will succeed. The returned results reflect that they were executed because I get the expected row counts, however, when I look in the database none of the work was actually done. I am also getting the one `InfoMessage` event as expected from the first transaction failing.

To be clear, my question isn't about the transaction failing... it's intentionally broken for testing the process.

Why are the other transactions not actually completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have 3 independent transactions if the happy path is followed but nested transactions if a catch block is entered and a `ROLLBACK savepoint` executed. `ROLLBACK savepoint` returns state to the savepoint but leaves the transaction open and does not decrement the transaction count. So if an error occurs in the first try/catch, the transaction remains open and the subsequent try/catch blocks run under that same transaction context started by the initial `BEGIN TRAN`. The transaction count will be non-zero after all complete and all work rolled back when the session ends.

It's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. What is the purpose of the savepoints with separate transactions? It seems you would want each to be all or none.

Comment: The SavePoints were so if the 2nd tran failed it wouldn't undo the first, or so I thought.  Do I need to reset the tran count or something?  Yes, each tran is supposed to be fully independent of the others.

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you ditch the savepoints and just be a BEGIN TRAN/do work/COMMIT in each TRY and a ROLLBACK in each CATCH, then each try/catch block will be independent and will not affect work done in previous transactions that were committed or rolled back. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Tried removing the save points, but the rollback isn't undo-ing the 2nd insert or the update of the 1st transaction when the first update fails.

Comment: @MrGadget, add the code you've tried to your question. The `ROLLBACK` in the catch block should rollback all uncommitted work.

Comment: Edited as requested...all I did was comment the SAVE TRAN and the name in ROLLBACK TRAN

Comment: We're closer though...the other trans were completed.

Comment: @MrGadget, include a script that actually demonstrates the transaction that's not getting rolled back, maybe simplified from your actual one. I get the feeling there's an detail not obvious from the information provided.

Comment: I've updated to show the full code.  There is nothing missing except the actual tables and fields.  The issue isn't in the inserts or updates themselves.

Comment: Oh crappola - it's working.  Stupid me misinterpreted my own results.

Comment: The final answer was that I should not have been using named save points.